# Copy a very large number of rows from one sheet to another, excluding blank rows in Excel 2010

Tags: arrays, excel, macros

I'm currently working on an excel workbook using the following formula to copy all rows from one sheet (Creation_Series_R) to another one, excluding empty rows.

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Creation_Series_R!C:C;SMALL(IF(Creation_Series_R!$C$3:$C$20402<>"";ROW(Creation_Series_R!$C$3:$C$20402));ROW()-ROW(Creation_Series_R!$C$3)+1));"")}

And the formula works very well. Except, when I did my proof of concept I only had a few rows but with the final data, I need to work on 20400 rows... adding to the fact that I have 17 columns, and 3 similar sheets with similar formula, my workbook takes an hour to compute every time I input just one value.

This workbook is designed as a way for a client to enter data, and then it reorganize the data so that it can be imported directly in our software. I already limited the number of data the user can enter per workbook (to their very big disappointment), so I can't really reduce it to less than 20400 rows (it's only a 100 funds financial data).

Is there a way, even maybe using macro, I could do this more efficiently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big block of array formulas is killing your performance *(time-wise)*.

If your data is in column **A** through **Q**, then I would use column **R** as a "helper" column.  In **R2** insert:

```
=COUNTA(A2:Q2)
```

and copy down.  The macro would:

- AutoFilter column **R**
- Hide all rows showing **0** in column **R**
- Copy the visible rows and paste elsewhere as a block

Comment: @NessaC ............ **Don't feel stupid!** .........array formulas are the right choice for small amounts of data...............the more data you have, the more the "help" column approach becomes attractive.